# Spring Boot -vs- JBoss | Что лучше?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, framework, jboss

Какой фрэймворк для Java программиста лучше: Spring Boot или JBoss?

- Как по мне, код с использованием JBoss выглядит более читабельно и гораздо проще. Но в чём на самом деле плюсы и минусы этих фрэймворков в сравнении?

Comment: Вопросы типа "почему А лучше чем В" должны быть хоть как-то обоснованы.

Comment: эээ ... простите, но вы сравниваете фреймворк с сервером... это все равно что сравнивать мышь с камнем... я к тому что это разные категории и вещи

Comment: может вы имеели в виду не JBoss, а Jakarta EE?

Comment: @МихаилРебров нет, я имел ввиду именно JBoss. В комментарии выше, вы сравнили JBoss и Spring как "мышь и камень". Но кто есть кто в такой аллегории? Англоязычные разработчики относят JBoss к категории инструментов «Веб-серверы». И самое интересное то, что с помощью JBoss на сколько я понимаю, можно реализовывать всё, что делается с помощью Spring. При этом разработчик использующий Spring переходит на высокоуровневый язык программирования, ближе к разметке, и не может делать то, что делает JBoss. Я бы сравнил программистов использующих JBoss и Spring как "производитель" и "дистрибьютор".

Comment: `Но кто есть кто в такой аллегории?` смысл как раз таки в том что это несравнимые категории и все равно кто там кто. Их нельзя сравнивать.

Comment: `Англоязычные разработчики относят JBoss к категории инструментов «Веб-серверы»` его все относят к категории «Веб-серверы», потому что по факту JBoss им и является. и именно поэтому его нельзя сравнивать со спрингом

Comment: Ты можешь реализовать приложение на Спринге и задеплоить его на JBoss

Comment: @МихаилРебров В англоязычном stack-e смотрят на этот вопрос по разному. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627839/spring-vs-jboss#:~:text=JBoss%20Microcontainer%20is%20a%20lightweight,can%20run%20easily%20in%20tomcat.

Comment: Там пишут, что в JBoss имеется `DI`, что вполне естественно, т.к. он должен поддерживать EJB, который входит в стек Java EE, с которым я и предлагал вам выше сравнивать Спринг

Comment: `При этом разработчик использующий Spring переходит на высокоуровневый язык программирования, ближе к разметке, и не может делать то, что делает JBoss.` - это вообще что такое и откуда вы это взяли? И там и там все пишется на Java

Comment: я могу сказать "Приложение реализовано на Spring Framework"...про JBoss я такого сказать не могу и что вы предполагаете под "приложение написанное на JBoss" я не понимаю.

Comment: @МихаилРебров там много чего пишут, причём на разных сайтах - разные точки зрения... Я всё же хочу акцентировать внимание на том, что программист использующий JBoss может делать всё, а разработчик на Spring только "верхнюю часть", как производитель и дистрибьютор, или даже в каком-то смысле - потребитель. Фундамент бизнес-логики - производство.

Comment: @МихаилРебров "И там и там все пишется на Java", но логика и в конечном счёте методы, в том числе продукция, всё же "чуточку" разные (например: IoC).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138870/discussion-between-vitaliy-m-v-and--